# Cart Rule to apply single "big box" shipping if item matches attribute

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm trying to setup a tricky thing here in **Magento 2.1**

We sell some sport stuf with a FLAT rate of EUR10 on all items. However their are some bigger items that require a "Big Box" which is EUR28.

The problem is, if even if there are multiple "Big Box" items selected, the shipping charge remains single Eur28 only, not multiple. So if multiple biog and small items are selected, the effective shipping remains Eur28 only.

We create an Attribute "Big Box" to those specific products and then in Cart rule, I set up a condition if item found in cart has attribute "Big Box" then

can you help me sort out the action?? what/where to set up ?

[image: screenshot of rule]

Answer (score 0):

That is where magento 2 fails :) clients wants magento 2 because its latest version but they don't know it has lack of extension... if u get same problem in magento 1 then u can easily do it via http://webshopapps.com/row/productmatrix-shipping-extension.html

So for magento2 , u need to edit table rates magento functionality and introduce big box attribute in table rates csv on the basis of which u can get that functionality done by using big box + qty

Also shopping cart price rules are for single items not for multiple items example if u setup price 10$ for single qty it wont be 30$ for qty 3 :)

Thanks